# jquery tablesorter2: How to sort the content of the generated Dropdown

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I use the jquery tablesorter2 (https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) with the filter widget.

Now I want to change the sort order of the values in the generated dropdowns (NOT the table-values) form asc to desc.
I have made a jsFiddle for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ru5zLjk8/

Here you can find a discount column. I would like to have its values sorted desc, so that the biggest discount is first in the dropdown.

There are some options, but nothing seems to fit:

```
  // each option has an associated function that returns a boolean
  // function variables:
  // e = exact text from cell
  // n = normalized value returned by the column parser
  // f = search filter input value
  // i = column index
```

Maybe this is completely the wrong place to do it?

How to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`filter_selectSource` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) to target that column ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ru5zLjk8/1/))

```
filter_selectSource: {
  5: function(table, column, onlyAvail) {
    // get an array of all table cell contents for a table column
    var array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a === b ? 0 : parseFloat(b) > parseFloat(a) ? 1 : -1
    });
  }
}
```

You will also need to add a `"filter-select-nosort"` class to the header to prevent internal sorting of the data.

I think I'll make this easier by adding a `"filter-select-desc-sort"` class to change the sort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works like a charm.
But is there a way to get rid of the hardcoded column (the "5" in this example)? I would like to reuse the js for different tables and only modifiy the html (add "filter-select-nosort").

Comment: The `filter_selectSource` option does allow using the header class name in place of the index. BUT, I just added the ability to add a "filter-select-desc-sort" class and it is now available in the master branch - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ru5zLjk8/2/).

Comment: Oh, I should point out that the change is only available in the `widget-filter.js` file, not the `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` file; that only gets updated when a new release is available.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will wait for the next release, thats not a problem.